# How can I call an IBinder android service from JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-service, android-binder

How can I call an IBinder service (lets say IPackageManager) from JNI and parse the Parcel returned by the method? For example I want to call what should be the same from adb to:

```
adb shell service call package 62 s16 "application.package.id"
```

Where 62 maps to "getinstallerpackagename", and should return me a JNI Parcel object with the installer package name (playstore/amazon store/whatever)

Is there a way to do this from JNI (without passing via java a Context instance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348028/10992173