# How do I define a custom class with Parcelable using Stable AIDL?

Tags: android-ndk, parcelable, aidl

With the introduction of Stable AIDL, defined parcelables are required to be structured (Parcelables with their fields defined in AIDL are called structured parcelables).
https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/aidl/stable-aidl

For instance, earlier we could define a custom header and implementation by providing an AIDL file that points to the header for your custom object using the cpp_header directive. This is not allowed with Stable AIDL.

How do I make the similar with Stable AIDL?

Basically this is what I try to achieve but with Stable AIDL.
[AIDL interface between Java and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284392/aidl-interface-between-java-and-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I want to achieve will be introduced in Android 14 for AIDL NDK backend.

https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/aidl/aidl-annotations#ndkonlystableparcelable

https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/aidl/stable-aidl#defining-an-aidl-interface