# How can a C++ client bind to AIDL service on Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-source, aidl

This is what I want to achieve

- I have an Android AIDL server implemented in Java
- I want to bind or connect to the Java server from my C++ code. My C++ code is *not* called by another Android app; instead, it is a *standalone* native program (with entry point `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`) running outside of a sandbox.

I used *aidl* binary to generate some .cpp and .h from my IMyService.aidl, but when trying to compile them with my C++ program, these generated C++ files refer to some other header files such as "<binder/IBinder.h>" which are not part of NDK. Instead, they are part of AOSP framework. I am new to AOSP framework, so my question is how to build a C++ standalone program with reference to AOSP framework? How do I set up the build environment so my build can find those files in AOSP framework?

I did some research and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284392/aidl-interface-between-java-and-c), but still I cannot find my answers after reading it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, I might be missing something in that article, but it is about how to call native C++ from a sandboxed Android app, it is not the siutation of my C++ program which is not running in a sandbox Android app, it is essentially a regular Linux process outside of Android Run-Time (or Dalvik).